# What can I do for displaying 1 to 1000 numbers in combo box in VB6.0 using coding?

Tags: vb6

I have tried a coding that contains a loop to display 1 to 1000 numbers in combo box. I am just a learner to Visual Basic. So I can't able to make that through coding. The coding is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Combo1_change()
    Dim a As Integer
    While (a <= 1000)
    Combo1.AddItem(a, [1]) = a
    a=a+1
    Wend
    End Sub
```

I have experienced "no error" but none of the number is displayed in the combo box while running. Please, help me by modifying the above code or redirecting me to any other method of inserting elements in combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Combo1_Change` event is definitely not the place you should be looking. That event is fired when the text in the combo is changed.  Try the `Form_Load` event instead:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim a As Integer

    For a = 1 To 1000
        Combo1.AddItem a
    Next

End Sub
```

Please note, a combo with 1000 items isn't the best user experience.